# UserControl Globalization

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

Hi how can I set culture information on a user control?  I have set up the resource file but I am unable to override the InitializeCulture() as it is not available in System.Web.UI.UserControl.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  I want to this programatically.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the PageLoad event of your user control you can set the culture of the current thread:

```
Me.Culture = "en-US"
```

Any internal framework calls after this point will use the current culture set for this thread, so for example the Convert.ToDouble() call will work here:

```
Me.Culture = "en-US"
Dim num as Double = Convert.ToDouble("1,000.50")
```

...but this would not work:

```
Dim num as Double = Convert.ToDouble("1.000,50")
```

... if we set the culture to French Canadian:

```
Me.Culture = "fr-CA"
Dim num as Double = Convert.ToDouble("1.000,50")
```

... this will work and correctly parse the string because the default decimal separator for the French Canadian culture is a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to change the culture of the current thread